# Oracle: Is there an equivalent to ROW in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, types, insert

When I instantiate a type in PostgreSQL, I can just make,

```
INSERT INTO mountain VALUES ('Meru',4567,ROW(6.8,-3.2));
```

and the ROW(...) will be typecast to the correspondent type in the table. In Oracle I have to make it this way:

```
INSERT INTO mountain VALUES ('Meru',4567,GeoCoord(6.8,-3.2));
```

and manually put the type in the INSERT.

Is there any way to make Oracle behave like Postgres?

EDIT: Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Mountain (
 Name VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT MountainKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Height NUMERIC CONSTRAINT MountainHeight
 CHECK (Height >= 0),
 Coordinates GeoCoord CONSTRAINT MountainCoord
 CHECK (((Coordinates).Longitude >= -180) AND 
        ((Coordinates).Longitude <= 180) AND
        ((Coordinates).Latitude >= -90) AND
        ((Coordinates).Latitude <= 90)));
```

Comment: What is the table definition for the Postgres table?  It will help us not familiar with the postgres syntax understand what it's doing.

Comment: I've added the table definition to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the ROW constructor of PostgreSQL in Oracle is the [object or collection constructor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions014.htm), as you've denoted in the posted code.

There is no singular expression however that would create an instance of the desired type. From the [Oracle 11g R2 database documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#i20453), it is evident that the constructor must be explicitly called to create and reference a type:

> To initialize a nested table or
>   varray, you use a constructor, a
>   system-defined function with the same
>   name as the collection type. This
>   function constructs collections from
>   the elements passed to it.
>
> You must explicitly call a constructor
>   for each varray and nested table
>   variable. Associative arrays, the
>   third kind of collection, do not use
>   constructors. Constructor calls are
>   allowed wherever function calls are
>   allowed.

Additionally, note that a default constructor is available for all types (except associative arrays), so you don't really need to write your own constructors.

There is also no difference in behavior when considering schema level types that are created using a `CREATE TYPE` statement - the constructor needs to be invoked in this case as well. From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjadv.htm#CACFHAIG):

> The system-defined attribute value
>   constructor requires you to pass the
>   constructor a value for each attribute
>   of the type. The constructor then sets
>   the attributes of the new object
>   instance to those values

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thanks :)